# PHP/CSS/JS - Disable print button while keeping document title

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to disable the print button on a page while keeping the document title and am having some problems in getting it to work.
It's either, disabled button and no document title or document title and see the button.
I have one or another but not both.

Here is my sample code, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with this? I'm stumped and have been searching for about a day now trying to make it work.

There is naturally more to the page than this but this is the code related to the button.
If you need more of the page please let me know.

If anyone can see where I've gone wrong with this I'd love a pointer in the right direction.

```
<head>
<?php //-----------disabling the header and footer when printing-----------------------// ?>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page 
    {
        size: auto;
        margin: 2mm;
    }
    @media print
    {    
        .no-print;
        {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>
<?php //-----------end disabling the header and footer when printing-------------------// ?>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>&nbsp;You are viewing the report preview for: </b> <?php echo $yearmonthd; ?>    
        </td>
        <td width="370px"> </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" onClick='window.print();document.title ="<?php echo "Report for  - "; echo $team1; echo " - "; echo $yearmonthd; ?>";' class="no-print" value="Print/Save this report"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: For your information, you can concatenate with the period in PHP.

Comment: Remove the `;` after `.no-print`

Comment: wow so simple, all it takes is an extra set of eyes.
thanks, that worked like a charm!

man i feel dumb :)

Comment: @user1998232 np, easily done; done forget to accept the answer ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the ; after the .no-print css declaration which is causing it to still show the button.

Try:

```
<head>
<?php //-----------disabling the header and footer when printing-----------------------// ?>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page 
    {
        size: auto;
        margin: 2mm;
    }
    @media print
    {    
        .no-print
        {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>
<?php //-----------end disabling the header and footer when printing-------------------// ?>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>&nbsp;You are viewing the report preview for: </b> <?php echo $yearmonthd; ?>    
        </td>
        <td width="370px"> </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" onClick="window.print();document.title ='<?php echo "Report for  - $team1 - $yearmonthd";?>'" class="no-print" value="Print/Save this report"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```